# Fetch geometry of an Address Location

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

If I were to search for a textual address (Let's say the address is "305 Quincy St NE"), how would I go about doing it in ArcGIS using the [ArcGIS API for Javascript](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/)?

My aim is to call a function which has the geometry of a place passed as its function argument.

```
function showLocation(evt) {
    map.graphics.clear();
    var point = evt.result.feature.geometry; // how do I get this value from a textual address?
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Locator`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/locator-amd.html) class. Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Using Locator to Find Address</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.14/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }
      body {
        background-color:#FFF;
        overflow:hidden;
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
      }
      #search {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 20px;
        left: 75px;
      } 
    </style>

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.14/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      var locator;
      var symbol;
      var locatorUrl = "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer";
      require([
        "esri/map", "esri/tasks/locator", "esri/graphic",
        "esri/Color", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/registry", "dojo/on", "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/keys",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, Locator, Graphic,
        Color, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol,
        TextBox, registry, on, parser,
        keys
      ) {
        map = new Map("map",{
          basemap: "topo",
          center: [-117.19, 34.05],
          zoom: 13
        });

        locator = new Locator(locatorUrl);

        symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
            SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE,
            20,
            new SimpleLineSymbol(
                SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                Color.fromHex("#EEAA00"),
                3),
            Color.fromHex("#002255")
        );        

        parser.parse();
        var box = registry.byId("textBox_address");
        on(box, "keypress", function (evt) {
            if (keys.ENTER == evt.keyCode) {
                var addressText = box.get("value");

                //This is the important part. Call Locator.addressToLocations.
                locator.addressToLocations({
                    address: {
                        SingleLine: addressText
                    }
                }, function (addresses) {
                    //Success
                    if (0 == addresses.length) {
                        alert("Address not found");
                    } else {
                        var address = addresses[0];
                        var pt = address.location;
                        map.graphics.clear();
                        map.graphics.add(new Graphic(pt, symbol));
                        map.centerAt(pt);
                    }
                }, function (error) {
                    //Failure
                    alert("Error: " + error);
                });
            }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="search">
        <label for="firstname" style="background-color: white">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="textBox_address" value="808 Travis St, Houston TX"
            data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" id="textBox_address" />
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You seem to be robbing me of the chance to answer my own questions :p +1 and accepted

Answer (score 1):

```
  var address = "305 Quincy St NE";         
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();     


    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var  longitude= results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

      } 
    });
```

Comment: This is for google maps. I didn't even tag this question with google maps.

Comment: This is use for all map but need for add google library..  because any other map not provide this type of services.. like leaflet map

Comment: But co-ordinates from google maps and co-ordinates used in ESRI maps are different, aren't they?

Comment: I learn about it.. solve your problem ...just switch latitude and longitude value....because  google map latitude value is  longitude of ESRI...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to Hiren's answer,

THe problem is not with the latitude and longitude, the problem is that you can not use Google Geocoder with any other technology different than Google Maps:

> The Geocoding API may **only be used in conjunction with a Google map**;
>   geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For
>   complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of
>   Service License Restrictions.

You can check it here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Cheers!